# Convert XML Nodes To Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

Consider the below sample:

```
declare @somexml as xml

set @somexml = '
<Settings>
    <Users>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <ID>5</ID>
    </Users>
</Settings>'
```

The above `XML` has some `ID` values that I need to convert to rows of data that can be used in a temp table to perform joins against.

I can't quite get the syntax correct, I've tried a number of samples that I've come across:

```
SELECT T.r.value('.','int') as id
FROM @somexml.nodes('/Settings/Users') T(r)
```

Returns:

```
|ID    |
|------|
|12345 |
```

The following:

```
SELECT T.r.query('.') as id
from @somexml.nodes('/Settings/Users/ID') as T(r)
```

Returns:

```
|ID         |
|-----------|
|<ID>1</ID> |
|<ID>2</ID> |
|<ID>3</ID> |
|<ID>4</ID> |
|<ID>5</ID> |
```

I'm getting close, but I want to remove the `XML` tags to just leave the ID values like so:

```
|ID |
|---|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
```

Here's a fiddle if you want to play/solve that way: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15887)

Any help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `T.r.query('.') as id` with `T.r.value('.', 'INT') as id`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.r.value('.','int') as id
FROM @somexml.nodes('/Settings/Users/ID') T(r)
```